# How to set the height of the pickerview in iPhone (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem regarding on how to set the height of `UIPickerView`.

I have a code in setting the width.

This,

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return 280;
}
```

Looks fine,

But how i Can change the height? I am new to iOS. please help me.

**EDIT**

I have done something like this.

```
CGAffineTransform s0 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.7);
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
picker.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(s0, t1);
```

But it squishes the `UIPickerView`. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: By above code you are setting only component width not pickerView width

Answer (score 1):

You can set your pickerView frame through coding. There are only three valid heights for `UIPickerView` 162, 180 and 216.

```
CGRect newframe=pickerView.frame;
frame.size.height=162/180/216;
[pickerView setFrame:newframe];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only three valid heights for UIPickerView 162, 180 and 216.

Answer (score 0):

set pickerview height to minumum possible i.e 162 then use

> UIPickerView *pickView=[[UIPickerView
>   alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 334, 162)]; 
>    CGAffineTransform t0 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0,pickView.bounds.size.height/2);
>
> CGAffineTransform s0 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale  (0.6, 0.6);
>
> CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (0,-pickView.bounds.size.height/2);
>
> pickView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(t0, CGAffineTransformConcat(s0, t1));

adjust the width accordingly to have minimum shrinkness..
Hope this will help you.